# Control start and stop position during a for-each

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0, xbrl

I am looking to find a way to control both start and end numbering that are added as suffix number to text "period". It seems the logic of my code makes `for-each` count 3 search matches (index 1-3), and due to using `if` to find `se:Bank` it reduces printout to 2 prints.

I know I can use `position() -2` to force the numbering to start at 0, but that will only work if I have exact same amount of data. As soon as data growths the `position() -2` will assume to step 2 positions minus and will not return zero as start.

I do understand that XSLT does what I actually ask for and returns presumable correct answer.

The interval of number I will be using is between 0 and 3. Most of the time in sequence.
It will be unknown in advance exact interval amounts.

I know there is a `start-at` using `<xsl:number>` but it did not solve my problem. Using `start-at` prints out same number twice.

The JSON file is aligned with a certain standard so I am not allowed to change the structure of the JSON file.

**Suspected problem:**

The "foreach" spans over more loops than wanted. In this case I need just for the system to loop twice for "se:Bank" and therefor return "period0" and "period1".

**Observation:**

I suspect that it probably would be better that I learn to extract when `xbrl:concept = se:Bank`. That would reduce the planned loop down to 2 search, thus being able iterate over them.

Here you find the [xsltfiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUS).

Below you find same code as in xsltfiddle:

**JSON data:**

```
<data>
{
  "report": {
    "facts": [
      {
        "xbrl:concept": "se:CompanyName",
        "value": "Great Company Ltd"
      },
      {
        "xbrl:concept": "se:Bank",
        "numericValue": 1000
      },
      {
        "xbrl:concept": "se:Bank",
        "numericValue": 3000
      }
    ]
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  
  <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

    <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->
    
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Printout periods -->
    
    <xsl:template match="//*[@key='facts']">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[@key='xbrl:concept']">
            <xsl:if test=". = 'se:Bank'">
            
            period<xsl:number value="position()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>period2period3`

**Expected result:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>period0period1`

Comment: If you want to output `position()` or `position() - 1` then `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="position() -1 "/>` suffices, there is no need to feed `position()` to `xsl:number`. Furthermore, I am not sure I understand your requirements correctly, but using a predicate `<xsl:for-each select=".//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank']">` instead of the of the nested `xsl:if` might help.

Comment: I am basically looking to find any key/pair that is equal to: "xbrl:concept": "se:Bank". Since that is 2 in the JSON data example, a `<xsl:value-of>` would then take care of the iteration thus start from zero and iterate only twice (resulting in "period0" and "period1"). The reason I was feeding `position()` is because `value-of` captures more data that needed, meanwhile `xsl-if` captures correct amount of data.

Comment: The `for-each` with a predicate would process two elements from your sample data and the result at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUS/1 is then "period0period1".

Comment: @MartinHonnen The code and result in the xsltfiddle is exactly what was needed. Please move your answer and link to xsltfiddle and I will approve the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output `position()` or `position() - 1` then `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="position() -1 "/>`, respectively, suffice, there is no need to feed `position()` to `xsl:number`.

Furthermore, I am not sure I understand your requirements correctly, but using a predicate `<xsl:for-each select=".//*[@key='xbrl:concept'][. = 'se:Bank']">` instead of the of the nested `xsl:if` should help to get the result you want, namely to process the two elements in the input sample meeting the condition in the predicate: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUS/1